# Finding all of a model based on embedded attribute

Tags: sails.js

In my sails application, I have one model that has an attribute

```
   flags: {
            "inappropriate": true, 
            "favorite": false, 
            "sticky": false
        }
```

I am trying to query the database with `GET media?where={“flags.inappropriate”: “true”}}`, which just returns all media entries and I only want the ones flagged as inappropriate.

Does anyone have any ideas how could be accomplished or what I am doing wrong?